# Jquery returning Object DomWindow

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to get the value of a link, but instead of the link as my object I am getting [Object DOMWindow] in the alert.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showToggle(link) {
   var x = this
   alert(x);
}
</script>


<a class="toggleLink" href="#" onclick="showToggle(this);">Sharing</a>
```

I am adding this code to a page. There is much more code that is not included. I only showed when I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're calling it, `this` is the same as `window`, hence the result. You want

```
var x = link;
```

Comment: Ugh, I did the same, can't believe how long I took to see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By link, do you mean the url? Also, you're using `this` as the variable, not `link`, which returns the `window`, not the link.

This will work:

```
function showToggle(link) {
   var x = link.href;
   alert(x);
}
```